# Need to execute gzip command with args via Apache camel-exec

Tags: java, linux, spring, apache-camel

I want to create a camel route to execute gzip command using camel-exec component that seems to be simple. But, I need to compress the input file without modifying the original file and the compressed file should be moved to another output directory.

I googled and figured out that it can be achieved by one of the following commands in linux:

```
gzip -c test_input_file.dat > /home/prem/myappdir/output/test_output.gz
```

or

```
gzip < test_input_file.dat > /home/prem/myappdir/output/test_output.gz
```

or

```
cat test_input_file.dat | gzip /home/prem/myappdir/output/test_output.gz
```

or

```
gzip -c test_input_file.dat | cat > /home/prem/myappdir/output/test_output.gz
```

All of the above commands are working fine in linux terminal. when I use those commands in camel route, none of them are working.

I am using 'gzip' as command and rest of the content is passed as command arguments to Exec component in camel route.

My Camel route to perform gzip task is:

```
<!-- route to demonstrate camel-exec -->
    <route id="camelExecDemo">
        <from uri="timer://kickoff?repeatCount=1"/>         
        <to uri="exec:gzip?args=-c /home/prem/Documents/input/test_input_file.dat &gt; /home/prem/myappdir/output/test_output.gz&amp;useStderrOnEmptyStdout=true"/>
        <log message="${body}"/>
    </route>
```

Someone please help! I am stuck with this issue.

Note: Simple gzip command with only one input file as argument is working fine in my route. But, I need to do it as I mentioned above.

**System details:**

Linux : RHEL (or Linux Mint 17) 
Camel Version: 2.11.0

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got it. I thought that creating a shell script for executing these commands is the only way to do this task. Later, I figured out that it can be done by 'sh' command (shell)  along with -c option which takes input from command string and executes them exactly like a shell script.

The following linux command will perform gzip without modifying original input file and moves the compressed output file to another output directory:

```
sh -c "gzip -c test_input_file.dat > /home/prem/myappdir/output/test_output.gz"
```

And my camel route is updated as follows:

```
    <route id="camelExecDemo">
        <from uri="timer://kickoff?repeatCount=1"/>         
        <to uri="exec:sh?args=-c &quot;gzip -c /home/prem/Documents/input/test_input_file.dat &gt; /home/prem/myappdir/output/test_output.gz&quot; &amp;useStderrOnEmptyStdout=true"/>
        <log message="${body}"/>
    </route>
```

Similarly it is possible to execute multiple linux commands sequentially with help of shell command and then it can be used in camel-exec component.

Thanks to the blog post where I extracted this idea:

http://zhanghaoblog.blogspot.in/2015/01/camel-exec-multiple-commdans-scripts.html